# I am unable to edit search engine robots from admin

Tags: magento2, search

[image]

I am trying to edit **search engine robots** from `content and theme configuration` but **no option to edit.**
Version `Magento 2.2.5` Any luck ?

Answer (score 6):

If you navigate to

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > XML Sitemap

and scroll down to `Search Engine Submission Settings`, you’ll find a setting that enables you to add the sitemap: directive to your `robots.txt` file

[image]

If you enable this, the URL towards your main sitemap `index` file (the one that contains just two URL-s, the URLs of your actual URL sitemap and image sitemap) will be added to the `robots.txt` file that’s dynamically generated on your website and if you visit `yourstore.com/robots.txt` you’ll see.

> Content > Design > Configuration

[image]

**In here you can open an accordion section titled “Search Engine Robots”.**

[image]

**PRO TIP**: If you’re having trouble saving the configuration at this step locally, try [this fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5666#issuecomment-233195345).

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

In the grid you will see a row which has only the website name no store view information, open that grid and you add the robots data.

Answer (score 2):

If it's still not updating delete the robots.txt file from the server and try to access it again from a browser. It will be re-created

Comment: At last, I have found. Its not showing in root but when accessing from browser, its showing. Strange